# stripping character from mysql result

Tags: php, string

I want to move some char eg.(/,\,/t..etc) from mysql result. Can I strip every char with one function? I want to know this function.Help me!

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the occurences with the empty string, [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) allows you to do multiple replace operations at once:

```
$string = str_replace(array("\t", '/', '\\'), '', $string);
```

Comment: The second parameter doesn't need to be an array: "If search  is an array and replace  is a string, then this replacement string is used for every value of search" - http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

To remove a set of characters from a string:

```
function removeBadCharacters($input) {
    // removes '/', '\\' '\t'
    return preg_replace("@[".preg_quote("/\\\t", '@')."]@g", '', $input);
}
```

Comment: Please don't use regular expressions for such trivial tasks, you'll make your code less readable, slower, error-prone and teach others bad practice. Example error: If you decide to escape the at-sign later-on you will run into trouble. You should preg_quote() the values.

Comment: +1 for teaching me a new function, didn't know about that one.